# Font weight for Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I'm using this font

```
\usefonttheme[stillsansserifmath,stillsansseriftext,stillsansserifsmall]{serif}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
```

However, I would like to have font sharper, thiner. How is it possible to get it?

Answer (score 4):

use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[light]{kpfonts}
```

Comment: Both are awful in my opinion. Any other suggestions?